# unexpected AST node: < on update query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple hql query :

```
"update Container container set container.obsolete = (container.maxLaunchingTime < ?2)"
```

But when i try to create the query from the session, hibernate throw an exception :

```
Method threw 'org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException' exception.

unexpected AST node: < near line 1
```

Is it possible with hibernate to create an upate query with an operation into the set statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [HQL Updates](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-update) reads:

> The BNF for UPDATE statements is the same in HQL and JPQL:
>
> ```
> update_statement ::=
>     update_clause [where_clause]
>
> update_clause ::=
>     UPDATE entity_name [[AS] identification_variable]
>     SET update_item {, update_item}*
>
> update_item ::=
>     [identification_variable.]{state_field | single_valued_object_field} = new_value
>
> new_value ::=
>     scalar_expression | simple_entity_expression | NULL
> ```

Now it's still unclear what exactly a `scalar_expression` or `simple_entity_expression` is. But I fear a computational expression like `x < y` is not subset of both.

In your simple example case you can possibly work around this by invoking two updates:

```sql
update Container container set container.obsolete = 1 where container.maxLaunchingTime < ?2
update Container container set container.obsolete = 0 where container.maxLaunchingTime >= ?2
```

---

As it is claimed that the BNF for HQL UPDATE is the same as for JPQL, we can extend the elaboration to [JPQL BNF from here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bnf) or [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#Update):

> ```
> update_statement ::= update_clause [where_clause]
>
> update_clause ::= UPDATE abstract_schema_name [[AS] identification_variable] SET update_item {, update_item}*
>
> update_item ::= [identification_variable.]{state_field | single_valued_association_field}= new_value
>
> new_value ::= simple_arithmetic_expression | string_primary | datetime_primary | boolean_primary | enum_primary simple_entity_expression | NULL
>
> simple_arithmetic_expression ::= arithmetic_term | simple_arithmetic_expression {+ |- } arithmetic_term
>
> simple_entity_expression ::= identification_variable | input_parameter
>
> arithmetic_term ::= arithmetic_factor | arithmetic_term {* |/ } arithmetic_factor
>
> arithmetic_factor ::= [{+ |-}] arithmetic_primary
>
> arithmetic_primary ::= state_field_path_expression | numeric_literal | (simple_arithmetic_expression) | input_parameter | functions_returning_numerics | aggregate_expression
>
> functions_returning_numerics ::= LENGTH(string_primary)| LOCATE(string_primary,string_primary [, simple_arithmetic_expression]) | ABS(simple_arithmetic_expression) | SQRT(simple_arithmetic_expression) | MOD(simple_arithmetic_expression, simple_arithmetic_expression) | SIZE(collection_valued_path_expression)
>
> aggregate_expression ::= {AVG |MAX |MIN |SUM}([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) | COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_field_path_expression | single_valued_association_path_expression)
>
> single_valued_association_path_expression ::= identification_variable.{single_valued_association_field.}* single_valued_association_field
>
> string_primary ::= state_field_path_expression | string_literal | input_parameter | functions_returning_strings | aggregate_expression
>
> datetime_primary ::= state_field_path_expression | input_parameter | functions_returning_datetime | aggregate_expression
>
> boolean_primary ::= state_field_path_expression | boolean_literal | input_parameter |
>
> enum_primary ::= state_field_path_expression | enum_literal | input_parameter |
>
> where_clause ::= WHERE conditional_expression
> ...
> ```

So finally we can see that expressions like `set property = 4+5` or `set property = 8/2` is part of the language while `set proeprty = 1 < 3` is not.